# Class that should not be instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I want to create a class hierarchy in which I have a class `Block` which can be instantiated by itself. Then I have a class `List` which inherits from `Block` and contains methods common to all lists, and finally I have classes `OrderedList`, `LableledList` etc that inherit from `List`. I want people to be able to instantiate `OrderedList` etc, but not `List`.

In other words, you can instantiate a plain `Block` and you can instantiate an `OrderedList` that inherits from `List` that inherits from `Block`, but you can't instantiate `List`.

All attempts to Google this lead to Abstract Base Classes, but none provides and example that fits this case and I am having trouble extrapolating.

Comment: You specify `class List(metaclass=ABCMeta):` in the class declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following conversation with the interpreter should show how this is possible. After inheriting from the Abstract Base Class with `Block`, you only need to mark the initializer on `List` as being an `abstractmethod`. This will prevent instantiation of the class without causing problems for child classes.

```
>>> import abc
>>> class Block(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


>>> class List(Block):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, data, extra):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.extra = extra


>>> class OrderedList(List):
    def __init__(self, data, extra, final):
        super().__init__(data, extra)
        self.final = final


>>> instance = Block(None)
>>> instance = List(None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    instance = List(None, None)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class List with abstract methods __init__
>>> instance = OrderedList(None, None, None)
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes so much clear! So Block can inherit from ABC and still be instantiated. It is marking `init` as @abstractmethod that makes it impossible to instantiate the class. So no multiple inheritance needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from `ABC` located in the `abc` module and make methods that are implemented in base classes (that inherit from `List`) `@abstractmethod`s (a decorator located in `abc`):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class List(ABC, Block):

    @abstractmethod
    def size(self):
        return 0
```

Having an ABC with `@abstractmethod`s defined forbids from instantiation.

Comment: No, my list has nothing to do with python lists at all (its about textual lists). And I need List to inherit from `Block`, and I need several methods in `List` to not be abstract so that they can be inherited by `OrderedList`. It's that combination of things that I am having trouble figuring out.

Comment: @MarkBaker you don't need to make *all methods* abstract; just those you need to re-implement. You can have "common" methods in `List` and use them without issue in any sub classes. All methods defined as `abstract` in `List` require to be implemented in sub classes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your List class should have ABCMeta as a metaclass and make the init methods abstract.

```
from abc import ABCMeta
class List(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    __init__():
        pass
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Answer (score 0):

The "one and obvious" way to do this is to use ABCMeta and mark some methods as abstract as documented on other answers.

But if in your case you don't have a set of methods that one has to override in a mandatory way (let's suppose your `__init__` is reusable in some cases, and other of the list methods as well):

In that case you can create a `__new__` method that checks if the clas being istantiated is the own class, and raises.  To do that,  you have to use teh magic `__class__` variable that is documentend only in corners of Python docs - if you as much as use the `__class__` variable in any method body, it will automatically take the value of the class where it was declared, at run time. It is part of the parameterless  `super` mechanism of Python 3.

Thus:

```
class List(Block):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if cls is __class__:
            raise TypeError(cls.__name__ + " can't be directly instantiated")
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
```

Btw, you *should* give preference for the ABCMeta abstractmethods if your pattern allows it. Note that if your classes use a custom metaclass it will conflict with the ABCMeta as well - so you may need to resort to this as well

(If you don't further customize `__new__`, then you'd better not pass `args` and `kw` upstream on the `__new__` method: Python's `object.__new__` ignore extra args if `__init__` is defined but `__new__` is not in the subclasses - but if both are defined it raises an error)